# Merging jQuery Instagram and Animated Responsive Grid plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, merge, responsive-design, instagram

I am trying to work on a personal project. www.blandydoes.co.uk

Let me bring you up to speed. I have two plugins installed on that page. One is called jQuery Instagram...

https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram

...the other is called Animated Responsive Grid...

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/

Independently both plugins function fine when setup.

**What I have done is tried to merge them**

I have initiated the jQuery Instagram plugin to generate a UL list of images (ul.instagram) instead of divs which it was meant to do. This works fine if I just create a UL with class name of instagram by itself. It generates the list and I can style it into a grid if need be. Check Firebug to see the list being generated.

Next I installed the Responsive Grid plugin and created the container div called #ri-grid.

The plugin is then initiated to find that div and is meant to find the ul list os links with images inside, remove the images and append the src of that image to the link as a background-image.

Again is I run that plugin with a ul list of static images surrounded by the link tag as the demo suggest, it functions fine.

**BUT**

Although the instagram plugin is generating that ul list of links with images, providing the src of the image too for some reason the responsive plugin is not taking the image src appended it to the link and removing that image, instead it is just "hiding" the list...

Anyone have any clues as to what conflict is going on?

There is nothing in Firebug console to say there is an error.

If you look at the page I have created a static list of images which works fine, and I have created a seperate automatically generating instagram list too.

www.blandydoes.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to think that this may never be solved. I will keep working away at it though. :-)